# Distributed processing - Apache Spark, Flink, Samza, Siddhi, Hazelcast Jet

Tags: apache-spark, complex-event-processing, stream-processing, hazelcast-jet

Imagine a processing system that receives data from other internal systems, or from internet exposed REST endpoints. Once received, set of (background) tasks (compute a response from input based on db or other webservices) work on the data in parallel, some sequential one-after-another, or some tasks at the completion of few parallel tasks. The final (edge) task can send the result to an external webservice or deposit into a database table.

The tasks can be designed as a simple services that process messages from `message-queues` delivered to it by other such services, and send the result to another queue for further processing. Instead of queue, the system can use streams to process. I find this approach (writing services connected by message broker) have to repeat handling their failure scenarios, scaling & throughput.

Are there any specific frameworks (like Flink or Samza or Storm or Airflow or Siddhi or Hazelcast Jet) to implement such tasks and deploy them into a cluster that takes care of scaling & failure handling, instead of implementing each tasks as verbose services (ex., in spring) & scale them independently.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like Hazelcast Jet could do this all in one deployed job/pipeline: ingest data from a REST endpoint, enrich from side inputs ("db or other webservices"), process the data in a cascade of steps where each step is performed in a data-parallel fashion, and finally push the data to another queue.

Such a job can run for an unbounded amount of time, on a cluster of machines. The only problem I see is restarting after failures because the REST data source is not replayable.

Comment: The REST request can be streamed into streming systems like Redis, from which the Jet can source it's jobs. However do you think, considering this to be critical system and not one transaction can be lost, this can be designed to run in fail safe way in Jet cluster? Because the Hazelcast itself don't persist anything to disk but keep data only in memory.

Comment: You get safety through replication across several machines. As far as dependable, replayable stream storage goes, Kafka is the current standard. Redis' features are on the same level as Hazelcast's, it is in-memory storage.

Comment: I have set redis persist data to disk and replication enabled, so any failure in master the slave would elect to master and continue to serve requests. Im more interested in the Jet or other framework failure handling side.

Comment: All distributed systems have that kind of resilience to failure, including Hazelcast. As long as you can provide a replayable data source, Jet can provide you the exactly-once processing guarantee.